# Why is ex instanceof DeadSystemException always false?

Tags: android

```
try {
 ... 
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

I know that the above block has caught android.os.DeadSystemException, so I changed the code to the following:

```
try {
 ... 
} catch (Exception ex) {
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    if(ex instanceof DeadSystemException){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
 }else{
    ...
 }
}
```

Android Studio gives the following warning:

> Condition 'ex instanceof DeadSystemException' is always 'false'

[image]

Could anyone shed some light on the cause of this?

**Update [2023-06-11]**

The stack trace of android.os.DeadSystemException reported by the app's analytics

Stack trace: android.os.DeadSystemRuntimeException:

```
android.os.DeadSystemException
        at android.net.nsd.NsdManager.discoverServices(NsdManager.java:949)
        at android.net.nsd.NsdManager.discoverServices(NsdManager.java:902)
```

Comment: BTW, you wouldn't do it this way.  You'd catch(DeadSystemException) directly, rather than using an if statement

Comment: How do you know that's what the block has caught?

Comment: @GabeSechan DeadSystemException seems to be supported by Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N. How should I catch DeadSystemException relatively simply?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica DeadSystemException was reported by app analytics before I changed the code.

Comment: Just catch it.  On versions below N, it just will never be caught because it doesn't exist (and most likely comes through as a different exception).

Comment: @GabeSechan In this case, Android Studio would give warning "Exception requires API level 24 (current min is 19): android.os.DeadSystemException. I am going to edit the question to add the stack trace of android.os.DeadSystemException reported by the app's analytics.
"